# android eclipse using method HdxUtil.GetPrinterPort

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm new here.
I need help, right now I'm coding for android and involved in 'have to connect to printer' thing.

I already import the HdxUtil library, but I don't seem to found method `HdxUtil.GetPrinterPort()`;

does anyone ever see this problem or familiar with it?
thank you

Comment: Are you using eclipe or android-studio? Are you able to access other methods from the library? Sounds to me like library importing issue

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?